# Azkaban Executor Java Process CPU usage very high, The "top" command shows high sys usage

Tags: java, cpu-usage, kvm, azkaban

I have an Azkaban executor server process, which is a Java service.

I noticed that when running a random sleep script, the CPU usage becomes very high, consistently exceeding 2000%, and the "top" command shows high sys usage.

I captured a jstack file hoping to analyze the cause, but I found that many of the stack traces were showing normal calls.

For example,

there are over 60 instances stuck at "at azkaban.execapp.JobRunner.run(JobRunner.java:652)",
[image]

where it hangs at "Thread.currentThread().setName",

and 96 instances stuck at "at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1019)".

I feel that these are supposed to be quick operations and should not be causing a bottleneck.

---

The same program, when run on a KVM machine (create by myself) with 10 cores and 86GB of memory, uses around 200% CPU and handles around 700 concurrent tasks.

However, when run on an Alibaba Cloud instance with 32 cores and 128GB of memory, the CPU usage goes over 2000% and seems to handle only about 400 concurrent tasks.

This makes me suspect there might be a performance issue with the cloud instance. How should I go about troubleshooting this problem?

this is my jstack file by Alibaba Cloud server

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXPfndCuhVHFKjQUKZYomvaRoZQ5Q5aP/view?usp=drive_link

and alibaba cloud server `ulimit -a`  output is as follows:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 506862
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 131072
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

add random sleep script:

```
rnumber=$((RANDOM%240+60));echo "benchmarks shell: sleep $rnumber";sleep $rnumber;
```

same thread stack:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can&apos;t be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: `when running a random sleep script` what do you mean by a sleep script? Add the code to the question. Also share the full stack thread of one of the thread to the question. Try to avoid linking to outside resources in questions.